# Browscap For Python

Tags: python, browscap

I was looking around, and couldn't find the Python equivalent of browscap (that I've used in PHP to detect what browser a given user-agent string is.

I'm hoping I'm not going to have to write my own.. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, it should do what you want: [browscap.ini-parser](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/267/).

Please note that even though it is on the Django Snippets website it is standalone and you can use it with whatever setup you have.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the pybrowscap library, it is equivalent for php get_browser : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pybrowscap/